# how to make the sides (left bottom and right bottom) with different height?

Tags: css

I have a design that I would like to achieve and I am finding it a bit hard to describe my problem.

I have tried looking at transform, but it is not what I need since transform rotates the div rather than making a diagonal ending. Is it even possible to achieve this using other functions?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **CSS3 transform skewY()** function with positive value for the parent and negative value for the child wrapper element to achieve the effect.

Check out this demo [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bugab/1/edit?html,css,output)

Or use `transform: rotate(45deg);` to rotate a div.

Comment: that would leave a gap on top div but i guess i can put another div underneath it. is this the only possible way?

Edit: taking a look at skew

Comment: yes this can achieve by using multi-pal divs here the tutorial for Non-Rectangular Layouts With CSS Shapes http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with shape:-

```css
  *{margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
  .container{width: 240px;margin:45px auto 0;}
.trapezoid {
  width: 0;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width:40px 0 40px 240px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: black;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
.trapezoid:nth-child(odd){
  border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;
  border-width:40px 240px 40px 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
    <div class="trapezoid"></div>
</div>
```